# Why is there a new() operator on enums?

Tags: c#, enums, .net-3.5, new-operator, enumeration

I just found out (by mistake) that enums have a new operator. Given the following

```
enum fruit {
    apple,
    orange,
    banana,
};

public void Grow() {       
    var item = new fruit(); //will give an apple
}
```

**What's the reason for such a constructor?** I expected to be able to use enumerations just for having a well defined value out of a set. A mistakenly used new operator just caused a weird, hardly spotable error to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enum` keyword defines a new value type (`fruit` in your sample).

As any value type, it has a default constructor (this is described at least in language specification, paragraph 4.1.2 "Default constructors"). Constructor behavior is also predictable, because it initialize enum instance into its default value - 0 (`apple` in your case).

There aren't any mistakes or errors here.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind that the default value of an enum is `0`, even if the enum only has non-zero values.

Comment: @Dennis do you have a link to that portion of the language spec you mention?

Comment: @Marcel: I've added a spec paragraph number. The spec itself is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx

Answer (score 1):

*All* value types must have a public parameter-less constructor (which basically initializes an instance to an all-zero bit pattern, if not overridden), so `new()` isn't only present for `enum`s; it's also present e.g. on `int`.

I am not sure if that is the technically correct reason for it, but I assume that value types are required to have a default constructor because it is value-typed fields that eventually make up the payload of an object, and C# wants to guarantee to you that objects are always initialized to a deterministic, sane default state. So let's say you have this:

```
class C { private int i; … }
```

You don't have to explicitly initialize `i` (not here, nor in the constructor). Not initializing the field explicitly has the same outcome as initializing it as `private int i = new int();`. If that were not so, `i` might initially contain any random value, which wouldn't be a very sane, useful default.

Answer (score 1):

With the "new" keyword you call the constructor of the enum, in this case this might be the default constructor. For enums you do not necessarily need the "new"-keyword to create an enum type, which is a value type and created on the stack.

Comment: Yeah, if possible I would forbid the new operator. I never encountered a situation where I actually needed to invoke it.

Comment: Indeed. I would also be proud if they would get rid of the goto statement. It is still used by minorities but it does more harm than good.